# Access and overwrite values in App.config file in class library

Tags: c#, vb.net, config, app-config

I gone through lot of threads about this topic but  did not get any solution.

First I created a windows application. In that I used app.config file to store some variables it worked properly. Then the application converted to class library. While extracting the varibles it gives only null values.

Any other option to get or set variables in config file in the class library

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you converted you code to some class library you have to remember that it will reuse web.config/app.config of an application, which references it. So I would suggest to add settings from "old" app.config to the configuration file of an application, which uses your library.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.............I changed the **application type** from windows forms application to class library........May i know how to add settings from the app.config file...Thanks

Comment: Class library cannot be used on its own so you have to have another application(or test project) which uses it.

Comment: I added the new window form application in the same solution and replaced its app.config with old one..but giving same null result.....i need to change anything else..... im new for programming.. Thanks

Comment: Hi now got it......we need to create one application and refer our dll project and add the settings of config file......But i have problem....we wont use this dll project in any other application we need to register as an addin file.. Thanks

Comment: @SethuRaman So you would have to provide more details to help you with it.

Comment: yes....Im creating addin dll for the solidworks software...once done we need to register using regedit.......In this dll project i used config file for storing the some of the user inputs......we need to update the config file and retract values.this is our requirement....

Comment: @SethuRaman So I believe you should store settings somewhere else(registry, ini file, something shipped with your addin).

Answer (score 0):

We can not use `app.config` or `web.config` in class library.  Add `app.config` for Console/Windows application or  `web.config` file for your web application which calls your class library then application will automatically takes and uses that configuration file.

Comment: Im creating add-ins for solidworks software...So i create a class library and  need to directly register the dll using regedit..i wont use this dll in any other applications   Thanks

Comment: @SethuRaman you cannot keep it in app.config  file you have to save it in your software config file